# Jni program not working in netbeans

Tags: java-native-interface

My jni program is not working in Netbeans but it works fine in commandline. Netbeans is giving an "Unsatisfied Link Error" Can anyone suggest me a solution for this.
I amusing Dev c++ to generate dll files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. check that you've set java.library.path. I.e. in netbeans
   open "project properties" -> "Run" and to field "VM Options" add -Djava.library.path="my folder with dll"
2. ensure that your dll and all dlls that yours one depend on them, are contained in %PATH%.